# Propositional Logic confused

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

i have managed to confuse myself with the below.

$\textrm{p} = \textrm{the team wins}$

$\textrm{q} = \textrm{its raining}$

Express the compound propositions with appropriate symbols and logic

"the team wins whenever its raining" my answer $p \implies q$

"neither the team wins nor its raining" my answer $\neg P \implies \neg$Q

"Either the team wins or its raining, but not both" my answer P exclusive or Q

"The team wins only if its raining" my answer $P \iff Q$

Answer (score 1):

*Not exactly*...

"B when A" is the same as "if A, then B", i.e. $A \to B$.

Thus, "the team wins whenever its raining" will be: $q \to p$.

Similarly, "A only if B" is $A \to B$.

Thus, "the team wins only if its raining" will be: $p \to q$.

[Neither... nor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR#Truth_table) is the conjunction of the negations: $\lnot p \land \lnot q$, and thus the negation of the disjunction: $\lnot (p \lor q)$.

Comment: thank you for your guidance